# Selecting only rows with more than one instructor

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am having trouble producing an output that only shows courses with more than one instructor...

```
def courses_multi_instructors(db):
'''Return the course number and instructor names for courses with more 
than one instructor. Note that this means the ID must be
the same for each instructor.'''

return run_query(db, ''' SELECT Course, COUNT(Name) FROM  Courses GROUP BY Course
HAVING COUNT(Name) > 1  ''')
`[('ANTA01H3F', 2), ('BIOA01H3F', 3), ('CHMA10H3F', 2), ('CHMB16H3F', 2), ('CSCA08H3F', 2), ('CSCA67H3F', 2), ('HLTC16H3F', 2), ('MATA29H3F', 2), ('MATA32H3F', 3), ('MATA67H3F', 2), ('MGAB01H3F', 3), ('MGAB03H3F', 2), ('MGAD65H3F', 2), ('MGEB02H3F', 5), ('MGFC10H3F', 3), ('MGMA01H3F', 4), ('MGSC14H3F', 2), ('POLA01H3F', 2), ('POLB80H3F', 2), ('STAB22H3F', 3), ('VPMA93H3F', 2)]
```

The desired output I would like to produce is...

```
    [('HLTC16H3F', 'C. Furness'),      ('HLTC16H3F', 'E. Seto'),      \
 ('MATA29H3F', 'G. Scott'),       ('MATA29H3F', 'X. Jiang'),      \
 ('MATA32H3F', 'E. Moore'),       ('MATA32H3F', 'R. Grinnell'),   \
 ('MATA32H3F', 'R. Buchweitz'),   ('MATA67H3F', 'R. Pancer'),     \
 ('MATA67H3F', 'A. Bretscher'),   ('MGAB01H3F', 'L. Chen')]
```

The table I use to get these columns are from this function...

```
def create_course_table(db, course_file):
'''Courses Table should be ID,Course,Section,Name'''

con = sqlite3.connect(db)
cur = con. cursor()

cur.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Courses''')

# create the table
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE Courses( ID TEXT , Course TEXT , 
Sections TEXT , Name TEXT)''')

# Read CSV File
csv_reader = open(course_file, 'r')
csv_reader.readline()      

# Insert the rows

for line in csv_reader:
    course = line.strip().split(',')
    ID = course[0]
    Course = course[1]
    Section = course[2]
    Name = course[3:]
    for names in Name:
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Courses VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)''', 
                    (ID, Course, Section, names))    

# commit and close the cursor and connection
con.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()
```

Any help would be appreciated. I tried doing this way but no success...

```
 return run_query(db, ''' SELECT Course, Name FROM  Courses GROUP BY Course
HAVING COUNT(Name) > 1  ''')
    [('ANTA01H3F', 'S. Dorland'), ('BIOA01H3F', 'S. Brunt'), ('CHMA10H3F', 'N. Thavarajah'), ('CHMB16H3F', 'K. Kerman'), ('CSCA08H3F', 'B. Harrington'), ('CSCA67H3F', 'A. Bretscher'), ('HLTC16H3F', 'E. Seto'), ('MATA29H3F', 'X. Jiang'), ('MATA32H3F', 'R. Buchweitz'), ('MATA67H3F', 'A. Bretscher'), ('MGAB01H3F', 'L. Harvey'), ('MGAB03H3F', 'G. Quan Fun'), ('MGAD65H3F', 'S. Ratnam'), ('MGEB02H3F', 'A. Mazaheri'), ('MGFC10H3F', 'M. Hasler'), ('MGMA01H3F', 'T. Dewan'), ('MGSC14H3F', 'P. Constantinou'), ('POLA01H3F', 'P. Triadafilopoulos'), ('POLB80H3F', 'C. LaRoche'), ('STAB22H3F', 'N. Asidianya'), ('VPMA93H3F', 'R. King')]
```

Any help/tip would be much appreciated!

Comment: It seems your database is not normalized. Where are the instructor names stored? In a different table? In Courses.Name?

Comment: @jemi, yes they are stored in Courses.Name

Answer (score 0):

The following query should return the rows you want.

```
SELECT Course, Name FROM Courses WHERE Course IN (
    SELECT Course FROM Courses GROUP BY Course HAVING COUNT(Name) > 1
);
```

Comment: @ Jemi Thank you very much. Learned something new today. Any resources to get better or practice with coding?